# Priority of primary key in multiple column index?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to sql and now working with MySQL.
I'm going through the concept of indexes and I'm not sure what would happen in the following case:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id         INT NOT NULL,
last_name  CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
first_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
INDEX name (last_name,first_name)
);
```

I have read that here, `last_name` or `(last_name,first_name)` can be used for lookup where as `first_name` cannot be used for lookup directly (not a leftmost index).

I have also read that `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE KEY` are indexed automatically. So, in my case where the `id` index comes? Don't it come as a leftmost prefix.

```
select * from test
where id=xxx and last_name==xxxx
```

will this call for a look up or searches the entire database?

Comment: The id field is the only field in the primary key, so it is the leftmost field in that index...

Answer (score 2):

First, your query is redundant.  The `id` comparison is sufficient.

The optimizer is going to recognize that two indexes can be used for the query.  I'm pretty sure that MySQL will choose the primary key index, because it is unique and clustered.  Hence, it is obviously the correct one.

If neither index is unique or a primary key, then MySQL will resort to statistics about the indexes (or arbitrarily choosing one of them).  You can read about index statistics in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-statistics.html).